# Wondering about "null" after replace

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly rusty in terms of JS, and recently encountered an issue I don't understand so I'm hoping someone can explain this to me.

```
var aList = {a:"aaa", b:"bbb", c:"ccc", d:null}
var aString = "a";
var anotherString = "d";
```

If I replace aString in the following manner:

```
aString.replace(aString, aList[aString]);
```

I get "aaa" as expected. However, if I do

```
anotherString.replace(anotherString, aList[anotherString]);
```

it results in "null" instead of null as I would expect. Why is this?

Edit: Noticed that I'd actually forgotten the null value in the object. Sorry guys. I blame it on being early in the morning :)

Comment: But your last replacement results in the string `"ddd"`... More generally, a string replacement should always result in a string, not in `null`.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/lubedec/1/edit?js,console — I don't know why you expect it to be `null`, but it isn't `"null"`.

Comment: Yes, the result is `"ddd"`, not `null` or `"null"`

Comment: Just tried this in Chrome DevTools console and I'm getting `"ddd"` as expected. You should maybe check again...

Comment: I just tried it . I am getting the result as "ddd" as expected. You should check once again

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot the actual null value in the object. It made no sense the way I originally posted it... Thanks for quick responses though!

Comment: Where do display the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it results in "null" instead of null as I would expect. Why is this?

Because you are replacing substrings of a string with new substrings. `null` has to be converted to a string in order to do that. Converting `null` to a string makes it `"null"` (you can see this by testing `"" + null`).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I expected null as the whole string was replaced. Thanks for the quick response!